# Excel - highlight differences in column

Tags: excel, highlight

I have 2 columns that are unordered. One contains 4800 results and one contains 4700. In theory they should have the same values, but they don't. How do I compare to make sure that a value in column A is in column B.

Please note, the columns are unordered so straight comparing with conditional formatting etc doesn't work. Ideally I would like to do a find on column B to see if which values are missing.

```
Contains 4700  Contains 4800
B     |        A 
_______________________
12            14
13            12
14            13
              15
```

I hope I have explained it enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a formatting rule which applies formatting based on a formula.
If you apply such a rule for column A, you can use the following formula to determine whether or not a specific value is in column B:

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)
```

Hope this helps you out.

P.S. Please pay attention to use the right cell reference so it determines the formatting based on the right field.

Comment: this is fine, but do I have to manually input that $A1...$A2 for every cell that i want to compare? And create a seperate rule for each?

Comment: Hi @Budyn, you don't have to. Please select the whole column for which you would like to add the conditional formatting rule. Then add Conditional Formatting based on the formula and add the formula mentioned above. It should then apply to the whole column.